# C++ Stroustrup's "std_lib_facilities.h" String struct – warning: comparison of unsigned expression

Tags: c++, c++11, build, sublimetext3, llvm

I am trying to get Stroustrup's "std_lib_facilities.h" header file (which is here: http://stroustrup.com/Programming/PPP2code/std_lib_facilities.h) to compile correctly in macOS Sierra, Sublime Text 3 (via build systems), Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.38). I have been fiddling with various settings but have not been able to avoid two warnings, even though the beginning "Hello, World!" program is compiling and running:

```
std_lib_facilities.h:107:8: warning: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false [-Wtautological-compare]
                if (i<0||size()<=i) throw Range_error(i);
                    ~^~
std_lib_facilities.h:113:8: warning: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false [-Wtautological-compare]
                if (i<0||size()<=i) throw Range_error(i);
                    ~^~
```

where the lines in question are part of:

```
// trivially range-checked string (no iterator checking):
struct String : std::string {
    using size_type = std::string::size_type;
//  using string::string;

    char& operator[](unsigned int i) // rather than return at(i);
    {
        if (i<0||size()<=i) throw Range_error(i);
        return std::string::operator[](i);
    }

    const char& operator[](unsigned int i) const
    {
        if (i<0||size()<=i) throw Range_error(i);
        return std::string::operator[](i);
    }
};
```

My C++ build settings file for Sublime Text is copied from [Can't build C++ program using Sublime Text 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485117/cant-build-c-program-using-sublime-text-2?rq=1) after my compiler did not seem to recognize C++11 as described in [How do I update my compiler to use C++11 features?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27385199/how-do-i-update-my-compiler-to-use-c11-features):

```
{
    "cmd": ["g++", "-Wall", "-Wextra", "-pedantic", "-std=c++11",   "${file}", "-o", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}"],
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "selector": "source.c, source.c++",

    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Run",
            "cmd": ["bash", "-c", "g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++11 '${file}' -o '${file_path}/${file_base_name}' && '${file_path}/${file_base_name}'"]
        }
    ]
}
```

I would appreciate it if anyone could help me understand why these warnings are happening and resolve them.

Comment: It means it is impossible for an *unsigned* value to be negative, and as such that part of the expression is always going to be *false*.

Comment: Right, that makes sense – I guess I have been assuming Stroustrup would not write such a redundancy and therefore there is something wrong with the settings for my compiler or other tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would remove the `i<0||` part and proceed.

Yes, the father of C++ is also human :)

Comment: Thanks, so by no means this is an issue with the settings on my compiler, version of C++, etc.?

Comment: @wander, it's a combination. You could tweak compiler settings to ignore such warnings.

Comment: @wander No, your compiler is generating a good warning.  It is possible to turn that warning off, but the warning is a good one, so you don't want to.